# ATG search API changes from 2006.3 to 9.1. i want the API differences so i can show them what we need to change

Tags: atg

ATG search API changes from 2006.3 to 9.1. i want the API differences so i can show them what we need to change

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, where all questions must be stated in the form of a question.

Answer (score 1):

The changes go beyond the API differences. 9.1 Search is quite different from 2006.3 or 2007.1 I'd say there is no simple, short answer to your question that would fit this forum.

See

ATG 9.1 Search documentation: http://www.atg.com/repositories/ContentCatalogRepository_en/manuals/Search9.1/

ATG 2006.3 Search documentation: 
http://www.atg.com/repositories/ContentCatalogRepository_en/manuals/Search2006.3/

Both link require ATG.com account.